# How to process query using FASTAPI?

Tags: python, get, fastapi

I have web server and index.html page that will be displayed when user key in local host:8000 into the browser. I am currently using fastapi and python. The index.html contains two text box and one submit button. It allow user to input data into the text box and the submit button will generate the query. For instance “GET /?query1=1&query2=2”. How do I go about processing the query? Create another endpoint?

```
app = FastAPI() 
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory= “templates”)
@app.get(“/“)
def root(request:Request):
return templates.TemplateResponse(“index.HTML, {request:request})
```

Comment: You should start with using the correct quotation marks and correct number of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get query parameters like this:

```py
@app.get("/")
def root(query1: int, query2: int):
    query1 = query1
    query2 = query2
    return templates.TemplateResponse(...)
```

or like this:

```py
@app.get("/")
async def root(request:Request):
    query1 = request.query_params["query1"]
    query2 = request.query_params["query2"]
    return templates.TemplateResponse(...)
```

You can read about query parameters [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/).

FastApi `Request` uses Starlette under the hood. You can read about Startlette `Request` [here](https://www.starlette.io/requests/).